# Is this the correct guide for tensorflow text summarization?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, textsum

Reading the tensorflow text summarization [model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum) it states "The results described below are based on model trained on multi-gpu and multi-machine settings. It has been simplified to run on only one machine for open source purpose."

Further in the guide this command is invoked :

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda textsum/...
```

Does this command not relate to cuda/gpu? Why is this command truncated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `bazel` command: `--config=cuda` means "use the CUDA build configuration (and generate GPU-compatible code)", and `textsum/...` means "all targets under the directory `textsum`" (i.e. the command isn't truncated and you should type the literal `...` when entering the command).

Comment: the generated code is GPU-compatible but will not run on a CPU? In other words does this model require a different machine architecture to other tensorflow models such as word2vec ?

Comment: In general, you should be able to replace `--config=cuda` with `--config=opt`, and generate optimized code for CPU instead. I'm not sure about the details of the text summarization model, but this should work in general for most TensorFlow programs.

Comment: Is it ok that bazel outputs this warning? "Config values are not defined in any .rc file: cuda"

Comment: @mrry any idea why I get this error? `jalal@klein:~/computer_vision/tensorflow/models$  bazel build -c opt --config=cuda textsum/...
The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace.`

Comment: @MonaJalal, I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39184573/3574081) covers the steps you need to take.