# Tensorflow text summarization setup : What is a workspace file?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, textsum

Reading the Tensorflow text summarization documentation setup : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum it states `clone the code to your workspace and create empty WORKSPACE file.`

I've created a new folder and cloned https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git to this folder , is that what is meant by 'clone the code to your workspace' ? What is an empty workspace file ? Is it an empty file named 'WORKSPACE' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WORKSPACE is a file that [bazel](http://bazel.org) (tensorflow's build system) searches in the directory hierarchy to determine the *root* of the project.

You can create a simple empty WORKSPACE file.

```
$touch WORKSPACE
```

in my setup I just created another directory

```
cd models
mkdir traintextsum
cd traintextsum
ln -sf ../textsum/ .
mkdir data 
touch WORKSPACE
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda textsum/...
```

keep in mind that the model is not trained. So to produce any meaningful result you would have to have some dataset that has the [Gigaword Dataset Format](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2012T21) to train it on.

The dataset has a license and thus is not freely available online (costs around $6K or $27K for a year subscription).

I am not aware of any other meaningful dataset that has that format besides the Gigaword itself.

Comment: I can use the model without Gigaword because ? : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/textsum/README.md states that 'In How To Run below, users can use toy data and vocab provided in the data/ directory to run the training by replacing the data directory flag.' so replacing the data directory flag gives : bazel-bin/textsum/seq2seq_attention \
  --mode=train \
  --article_key=article \
  --abstract_key=abstract \
  --data_path=data/data \
  --vocab_path=data/vocab \
  --log_root=textsum/log_root \
  --train_dir=textsum/log_root/train

Comment: @blue-sky so it seesm there is no way to make it works since it is not pre-trained and the `training set` that Google has used is apparently not free.

Comment: I get this warning: "WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: cuda" after running "bazel build". Thoughts?

Comment: @blue-sky "users can use toy data and vocab" how did it go for you did you manage to create a model and run was it a good model?